# How to produce bounding boxes for ID cards?

Tags: python, opencv, ocr

I am writing a code in python using the library opencv to OCR some data(fathers name, ID holder's name, DOB and PAN number) out of a PAN or Aadhar card. However as seen in the image below, if the object is a little cluttered, it produces overlapping bounding boxes according to the thresholded image(also below)

**

- THRESHOLDED IMAGE/ IMAGE AFTER VARIOUS PREPROCESSING

**
[image: THE THRESHOLDED IMAGE]

**

- END IMAGE AFTER DRAWING BOUNDING BOXES

**
[image]

This is the code I have used:

```
from __future__ import print_function
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from PIL import Image
import re
import numpy as np
from imutils import paths
import os
import pytesseract
import cv2
import argparse
import imutils
import glob
import xlsxwriter
from google.colab.patches import cv2_imshow

'''
ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-i", "--images", required=True, help="path to images directory")
args = vars(ap.parse_args())
'''
'''
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook(r'/Users/vd/Downloads/PAN Number extraction/example.xlsx') 
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet("My sheet") 
'''

rectKernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (13, 5))#returns matrix representing rectangular images filled with ones
print(rectKernel)
sqKernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (21, 21))
print(sqKernel)
row=0
col=0
i=0

#for imagePath in paths.list_images(args["images"]):
imagePath="/content/Tanvi-Papa-Pan-Card.jpg"
i+=1
print(i)
image = cv2.imread(imagePath)
image = imutils.resize(image, height=600)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)#colour conversion to gray
gray = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (3, 3), 0)#blurring(3x3) to reduce noise and for smoothening
cv2_imshow(gray)
blackhat = cv2.morphologyEx(gray, cv2.MORPH_BLACKHAT, sqKernel)#used to enhance dark objects on a light background
cv2_imshow(blackhat)
gradX = cv2.Sobel(blackhat, ddepth=cv2.CV_32F, dx=1, dy=0, ksize=-1)#GRADIENT IN X DIRECTION 
cv2_imshow(gradX)
gradX = np.absolute(gradX)#CHANGING ARRAY TO ABSOLUTE VALUES
(minVal, maxVal) = (np.min(gradX), np.max(gradX))#finding min value and max value in the matrix
print(maxVal,minVal)
cv2_imshow(gradX)
gradX = (255 * ((gradX - minVal) / (maxVal - minVal))).astype("uint8")
cv2_imshow(gradX)
print(gradX)
gradX = cv2.morphologyEx(gradX, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, rectKernel)#gives outline
cv2_imshow(gradX)


thresh = cv2.threshold(gradX, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
cv2_imshow(thresh)
thresh = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, sqKernel)
cv2_imshow(thresh)
thresh = cv2.erode(thresh, None, iterations=4)
cv2_imshow(thresh)



p = int(image.shape[1] * 0.05)
#print(p)
thresh[:, 0:p] = 0
thresh[:, image.shape[1] - p:] = 0
cnts = cv2.findContours(thresh.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
#cv2_imshow(cnts)
#print(cnts)
cnts = imutils.grab_contours(cnts)
cnts = sorted(cnts, key=cv2.contourArea, reverse=True)

for c in cnts:
    (x, y, w, h) = cv2.boundingRect(c)
    ar = w / float(h)
    crWidth = w / float(gray.shape[1])
    pX = int((x + w) * 0.03)
    pY = int((y + h) * 0.03)
    (x, y) = (x - pX, y - pY)
    (w, h) = (w + (pX * 2), h + (pY * 2))

    roi = image[y:y + h, x:x + w].copy()
    cv2.rectangle(image, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 255, 0), 2)
    #filename="{}.jpg".format(os.getpid())
    #cv2.imwrite(filename,roi)
    text=pytesseract.image_to_string(roi)
    #os.remove(filename)
    
     
    #p=re.compile('[A-Z][A-Z][A-Z][A-Z][A-Z]\d\d\d\d[A-Z]')

    #q=''.join(p.findall(text))
    print(text)
'''
    if q is not None:
        worksheet.write(row, col, i) 
        worksheet.write(row, col+1, q)
'''
row+=1  
cv2_imshow(image)
cv2_imshow(roi)
#workbook.close()
```

This results in overlapping bounding boxes in certain situations due to which the text in the part that overlaps doesn't get printed.

Is there any way around this? to get cleaner thresholding or bounding boxes etc.

Comment: I would suggest you use threshold on black (dark) and then use a horizontal morphology kernel to connect the text characters horizontally and not vertically. That way you can isolate the text bounding boxes from later processing.

Comment: @fmw42- thank you for your suggestion. I will definitely try it out.